# Find strong connected components of a Graph in O(V^2 + V*E) time complexity

Tags: algorithms

Given is an algorithm that finds the transitive shell of a graph:

```
Transitive Shell(G)
 for v in V
   BFS(G,s)
   for w in V with d(w) < infinity
   E* = E* U (s,w)
```

I've been knacking at this problem for a while, and I can't come up with a solution. Also no results for this on Google either. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components/). It is pretty well known that we can find all strongly connected components in $O(|V|+|E|)$.

The basic "gist" is to use DFS from a node $v$, and then [transpose the graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_graph), and apply DFS again. The nodes that have been explored in **both** DFS instances, *must* be the strongly connected component that $v$ resides in. Apply this a few times, and you will end up finding all strongly connected components (but you need to be a bit more careful in order to ensure the time complexity stays $O(|V|+|E|)$).